# Are there Eagle library templates for each package type?

Tags: design, eaglecad, library

Although some packages vary slightly from one-another, nearly all of them have the same PCB footprint and schematic symbol.

How do you guys actually make the footprint, for say, an LM317 TO-220 when it is not (at least by default) in the library?

I assume from scratch as I cannot see a "copy from another item" feature at least on hand, however that opens to major problems if one was done wrong.

I have heard of a default template library of most package types, that'd be amazing to use, however have not found it (or on search engines at first look) nor would I understand how to copy just (i.e. a TO-220 generic) template out and edit it in to my own library.

Any advice on what to do?

I may need to get a lot more proficient at this, as many parts I come across simply do not have libraries. I thought Element 14? (who bought cadsoft I believe) would have made a huge library with every one of their parts - that'd be amazing, again, no luck in search engine and am not even sure it is better than just DIY symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you are looking for is named 'ref-packages'.

Comment: You will probably find this question and their answers useful, too: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27236/missing-components-in-eagle-library

Comment: Easy to pass when there are so many filler libraries that are default, thank you PetPaulsen. Hopefully this question turns a few people looking for "eagle library templates" to the right answer, as I could not find in Google. :)

Comment: I guess no schematic symbols along with it, oh well, very simple to make as I go along.